# Map array index to matrix

Tags: c, arrays, openmp

My problem is this:
I've an array with values from 0 to 8(a[9]=[0,1,2,....,8] and I would map the indexes of array to a matrix 3x3. 
This is useful for me to develop the "Broadcast Multiply Rolling" algorithm to make the product of two matrices. 
Thank to everyone

Comment: Why not write the matrix array right away if values are fixed?

Comment: You should at least give it a try yourself before asking for help. What problems did you face, what errors you got?

Comment: I'm glad you found my answer useful.  Now ask yourself how you would calculate the indexes for an n-dimensional array.  It's not complex, it's a general concept, and it's something any C programmer should understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `index` is an index into a single-dimensional array of 9 elements, the array can be viewed as a two-dimensional 3x3 array with this:

```
int row = index / 3;
int column = index % 3;
int foo = array[row][column];
```